# Artikel nimmt die Endung vom Genitiv

Tags: article, genitive

Der Satz lautet:

> Menschen unterschiedlicher Kulturen sind unterschiedlich sozialisiert. Infolgedessen werden bestimmte Verhaltensmuster **der einen Kultur in einer anderen missverstanden.**

Ich kann nicht verstehen, wieso es zwei Artikel gibt. Was ist die verwendete grammatische Regel hier?

Answer (score 3):

*ein* ist im Deutschen ein ziemlich vielseitiges Wort. Es kann sein

1. ein unbestimmter Artikel. Das ist der häufigste Fall. "**Ein** Auto"
2. ein Zahlwort (Numeral) - "Jeder bekommt nur **ein** Stück Kuchen!"
3. ein Indefinitpronomen. - "Wenn man zu viel Kuchen isst, wird dem **einen** schlecht, dem anderen nicht".
4. Darüberhinaus kann "ein" auch in manchen Sonderfällen als Adjektiv oder als Adverb gebraucht werden.

In deinem Beispiel ist "eine" der Fall (3). Das Indefinitpronomen kann man (in deinem Fall) einfach daran erkennen, dass es in einem Pärchen mit "andere" (was auch ein Indefinitpronomen ist) gegenübergesetzt wird.

Es kommen also in deinem Beispiel nicht etwa zwei Artikel vor, sondern ein Artikel mit einem Indefinitpronomen. Vielleicht hilft auch das Folgende zum Verständnis: Im Englischen würde man dieses "einen" mit "the *one* ... or the other" übersetzen.

Comment: Da *einen* hier im Kontext *der … Kultur* steht, passt das nicht zu 3., wo es als Objekt eines Verbs steht.

Comment: @DavidVogt ein Indefinitpronomen kann halt beides sein - wo ist das Problem? So besser?

Comment: Für mich ist *ein-* bei 3. (in der aktuellen Version) und 4. ein Adjektiv; es trägt eine schwache Endung.

Comment: @DavidVogt "...wird dem einen schlecht, dem anderen nicht..." verstehe nicht, wie das ein Adjektiv sein soll. Es hat so viele nicht-Adjektiv-Eigenschaften, dass ich die gar nicht alle in einen Kommentar bekomme...

Comment: Für die Aufzählung der möglichen Bedeutungen kommt außerdem in Frage: Partikel eines trennbaren Verbs wie in *Er schlug den falschen Weg ein*.

Comment: @guidot Das hab' ich überlegt und dann mit Absicht weggelassen.

Comment: Schwache Endung und attributiver Gebrauch passen nur zu Adjektiv, nicht zu Pronomen; siehe auch die Duden-Grammatik unter Randnummer 446.

Comment: Leider verhält es sich syntaktisch-grammatisch so, wie @David schreibt, obwohl ich 'andere' von seiner Wortartzugehörigkeit eher wie einen Artikel (bzw. als Pronomen) empfinde, denn es wird u.a. zur Identifikation eingesetzt, was eine klassische Artikelfunktion ist [nicht  **diesen** Apfel, ich möchte **den anderen** (Apfel)]. *Ander-* ist für mich ein artikelhaftes Adjektiv. Als Pronomen sehe ich *einer anderen* anders als tofro im Beispiel nicht, sondern als Artikelphrase, bei der das Nomen weggelassen ist, um die Wiederholung von *Kultur* zu vermeiden, à la *diese Kultur oder jene ...*